# Javascript cross-domain request: localhost > https

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I'm trying to make an AJAX call from my localhost to a https URL.

Of course I get "XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://blablabla.com/example.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '`http://localhost:9000`' is therefore not allowed access. "

Is that even possible without touching the server?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't matter if it's https either, any ajax request where protocols, domains or ports doesn't match is not allowed, unless the server sends JSONP or allows CORS.

Comment: Without touching blablabla.com, yes, but you'll have to use your localhost server or another 3rd party server as a proxy between your web page and the target server. Send the request to the "proxy" server that then sends a request and gets the response from the target server and returns it to your script.

Comment: I see. Thanks guys.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy is a good compilation of different techniques (y)